# script code to restrict Date value picker to specific range

Tags: html, typescript, google-apps-script, datepicker

I need your help, I'm trying to prevent my customers from picking date more than 10 days in the future.

I've tried the following code which works correctly during the month if the rest days of the current month are more than 10 days, but now it doesn't work, because we are in 22th of January so the code doesn't work,

```js
var today = new Date();
var future = new Date();
var dd = today.getDate();
var mm = today.getMonth() + 1; //January is 0!
var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
if (dd < 10) {
  dd = '0' + dd
}
if (mm < 10) {
  mm = '0' + mm
}

today = yyyy + '-' + mm + '-' + dd;
var ndd = dd + 10;
future = yyyy + '-' + mm + '-' + ndd;
document.getElementById("bdate").setAttribute("min", today);
document.getElementById("bdate").setAttribute("max", future);
```

```html
<div class="item" dir="rtl" style="text-align:right">
  <label for="bdate" style="font-size:20px;">تاريخ الدفع<span>*</span></label>
  <input dir="ltr" style="text-align:center" id="bdate" type="date" name="entry.624495733" placeholder="اضغط للاختيار" required/>
  <i class="fas fa-calendar-alt"></i>
</div>
```

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/). Please include the framework/CDN code of the datepicker you are using if any

Comment: I just only need you to help me with small editing for the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your

`var ndd = dd + 10;`

makes 2210 today because you are concatenating to a strings.

You need to use two dates or reuse one date for both dates

```js
const today = new Date();
const todayString = today.toISOString().split('T')[0]
const future = new Date(); 
future.setDate(future.getDate()+10);
const futureString = future.toISOString().split('T')[0]
console.log(todayString,futureString)
document.getElementById("bdate").setAttribute("min", todayString);
document.getElementById("bdate").setAttribute("max", futureString);
```

```html
<div class="item" dir="rtl" style="text-align:right">
  <label for="bdate" style="font-size:20px;">تاريخ الدفع<span>*</span></label>
  <input dir="ltr" style="text-align:center" id="bdate" type="date" name="entry.624495733" placeholder="اضغط للاختيار" required/>
  <i class="fas fa-calendar-alt"></i>
</div>
```